# How can i synchronize server config, program code in load balanced environment in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If i want to use AWS Elastic Load Balancing for hosting multiple instance in amazon web services, there are several questions i don't understand how it works:

```
1) how can i synchronize files (server config) between multiple instances? <br>
2) how can i synchronize files (program code) between multiple instances? <br>
3) how can i run a ssh command across all the instances at a time?
```

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: don't close my question, the question is related to deploy source code

Answer (score 0):

In a Load Balanced environment (and this applies to AWS and any other), you'll want to develop and/or use a system that will update/replace your servers for your automatically. Don't try to do this manually, one-by-one.

Updating server configuration and program code can be done using configuration management tools. Some include:

- Puppet
- Ansible
- Chef

Other options are to pre-make AMI images that you will use in your Auto Scaling groups. When you want to update the server config or update the program code, you can update a template EC2 instance and produce a new AMI image to use in your Auto Scaling groups.

Another option is to use something like Elastic Beanstalk. Amazon EB will manage the server configuration and application versioning and updates for you.

Finally, any combination of the above can be used too.

For your question 3, you cannot SSH across all instances at a time. The best you can probably do is have a local script that SSH's into each instance one-at-a-time and runs a remote script server-side.